# What does the subscript || ≥ a mean here?

Tags: probability-theory

[image]

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Where does this come from? Please see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1_{|X|\geq a}$ stands for the random variable with is $1$ when $|X| \geq a$ and $0$ when $|X| <a$.